# Inconsistent formulas when solving recurrent equations using sympy.rsolve_poly

Tags: python, sympy

I am getting inconsistent formulas when using `sympy.rsolve_poly` to solve recurrent equations.

This first piece of code solves `a(n+1) = a(n) + 4n^3` with `a(0) = 0`

```
from sympy import rsolve_poly, symbols
n = symbols('n',integer=True)
formula = rsolve_poly([-1, 1], 4*n**3, n)
print(formula)
# output:
# C0 + n**4 - 2*n**3 + n**2
```

This formula correctly calculates:

```
a(0)=0
a(1)=0
a(2)=4
a(3)=36
a(4)=144
a(5)=400
```

However, when adding a little change: `a(n+1) = 2*a(n) + 4n^3` with `a(0) = 0` with the following code to get the formula:

```
from sympy import rsolve_poly, symbols
n = symbols('n',integer=True)
formula = rsolve_poly([-2, 1], 4*n**3, n)
print(formula)
# output:
# -4*n**3 - 12*n**2 - 36*n - 52
```

This is completely wrong. I have been struggling to figure it out to no avail.

Solution using http://wolframalpha.com

Input:
a(n + 1) = 2 a(n) + 4 n^3 | a(0) = 0

Alternate form:
{a(n + 1) = 2 (2 n^3 + a(n)), a(0) = 0}

Recurrence equation solution:
a(n) = 4 (-n (n (n + 3) + 9) + 13 2^n - 13)

Calculated correctly:

```
a(0)=0
a(1)=4
a(2)=40
a(3)=188
a(4)=632
```

[EDIT 04/03/2020]
Tried to use rsolve in lieu of rsolve_poly as suggested by JohanC:

```
from sympy import Function, symbols, rsolve

y = Function('y')
n = symbols('n')
f = y(n)-2*y(n-1)-4*n**3
sol = rsolve(f,y(n))
print(sol)

# Output:
2**n*C0 + C0*(4*n**3 + 12*n**2 + 12*n + 4)
```

Interrestingly, solving with `y(0) = 0` returns `None`, but solving with `y(1) = 4` returns an output:

```
from sympy import Function, symbols, rsolve

y = Function('y')
n = symbols('n')
f = y(n)-2*y(n-1)-4*n**3
sol = rsolve(f, y(n), {y(1) : 4})
print(sol)

# Output:
2*2**n/17 + 8*n**3/17 + 24*n**2/17 + 24*n/17 + 8/17

a(0)=0.5882352941176471
a(1)=4.0
a(2)=13.176470588235295
a(3)=31.05882352941176
a(4)=60.70588235294118
```

The question is how to set y(0) = 0?

Comment: Did you try the same directly with `rsolve`?

Comment: I will try and come back to you. The documentation indicates that the function should be made up of hypergeometric terms. However, I have the polynomial 4n^3. In fact, the documentation is quite poor and does not indicate the limitations of each function. I would rather get None than some meaningless results. Note: I have tried a lot of things including rsolve_hyper since the solution given by Wolfram involves 2^n. It's late here and I have to sleep, but will put an extra effort tomorrow and update you.